# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str. Except it is an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Taking my first course in computer science so apologies in advance for potentially a basic mistake.

The point of this is to print a sorted index of words entered by the user (With the position included after the key).

I have researched this problem but I still don't know why I'm getting this error. It states that the problem occurs in line 26 specifically.
(print(key + " " + sortIndex[key]) <--- line 26

So apparently sortIndex[key] is seen as a string instead of an integer. Even my lab TA (still a student) couldn't figure this one out.

The commented print statement within the first function is meant to show what the index looks like if unsorted in case it helps.

```
def buildIndex(text):
    index = {}
    words = text.split()

    position = 0
    while position < len(words):
        nextWord = words[position]
        if nextWord in index.keys():
            ref = index[nextWord]
            ref.append(position)
            index[nextWord] = ref
        else:
            index[nextWord] = [position]
        position += 1
    
#    print(index)
    return index


def displayIndex(index):
    sortIndex = sorted(index.keys())
    for key in sortIndex:
        print(key + " " + sortIndex[key])

def main():
    text = str(input("Enter some text to index: "))
    displayIndex(buildIndex(text))

main()
```

Any and all help is appreciated!
Also, this is my first post here so if I did something wrong let me know.

Comment: Yes, it is a string. Because it is one value in the list, **not an index**.

Comment: btw, line 26 is not the one you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def displayIndex(index):
    sortIndex = sorted(index.keys())
    for key in sortIndex:
        print(key + " " + sortIndex[key])
```

`sortIndex` is a list containing the (string) keys from the dictionary `index`. You then try to index into `sortIndex` using the key that you just took out of `sortIndex`. I think you probably intended to use the key to index into `index` instead. I.e.:

```
print(key + " " + index[key])
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Can't believe I missed that
Also very helpful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I added a simple print statement to check:

```
def displayIndex(index):
    sortIndex = sorted(index.keys())
    print sortIndex
    for key in sortIndex:
        print key, type(key)
        print(key + " " + sortIndex[key])
```

The output shows that you aren't using an integer:

```
['I', 'Now', 'a', 'construct', 'rhyme', 'will']
I <type 'str'>
```

---

Instead, try looking up the index of the word; I *think* that's what you want.

```
def displayIndex(index):
    sortIndex = sorted(index.keys())
    print sortIndex
    for key in sortIndex:
        # print key, type(key)
        print(str(sortIndex.index(key)) + " " + key)

def main():
    text = "Now I will a rhyme construct"
    displayIndex(buildIndex(text))
```

main()

The output from this is ...

```
['I', 'Now', 'a', 'construct', 'rhyme', 'will']
0 I
1 Now
2 a
3 construct
4 rhyme
5 will
```